# ProducerRequest send [...255, 255, 255, 255..] when the key is empty

Tags: apache-kafka, protocols, kafka-producer-api

I'm using the [kafka-node](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node) client and I'm trying to understand the kafka protocol. I have this basic producer example, which send `message` without `key`:

```
producer.send([
    { topic: "mytopic", messages: ["hi"] },
],
```

And if I analyse the frame of the message (`tcpdump`) I get:

```
[
    79,   CRC
    44,
    52,
    245,  END CRC
    0,    magic_byte
    0,    partitions
    255,  ================= 
    255,
    255,
    255, ==================
    0,   size message begin 
    0,
    0,
    2,   size message end
    104,  'h'
    105,  'i'
]
```

So I don't understand why I have `4` bytes at `255` when the key is empty. I can't find anywhere in the documentation the explanation of this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is of type `bytes`. Bytes uses a `signed int32` to specify the length of data.

If the key is `null`, the length is set to `-1`. The representation of `-1` as a `signed int32` is `255,255,255,255` (`0xffffffff`)

It's similar for the message value. First you have the length as a `signed int32`, `0,0,0,2`, followed by the actual 2 bytes.

```
[
    79,   CRC
    44,
    52,
    245,  END CRC
    0,    magic_byte
    0,    partitions
    255,  size key begin 
    255,  -1 as the key is null
    255,
    255, size key end
    0,   size message begin 
    0,
    0,
    2,   size message end
    104,  'h'
    105,  'i' ]
```

See this section in the Kafka Protocol Guide: http://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_types

> bytes, string - These types consist of a signed integer giving a
>   length N followed by N bytes of content. A length of -1 indicates
>   null. string uses an int16 for its size, and bytes uses an int32.